# FolderWatcher.Created fires, but file doesn't exist- NAS

Tags: c#, linux, nas

I'm facing a very weird problem.
I have a C# project with a FolderWatcher.OnCreate on a specific LAN path.

```
   FolderWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FSW_Created);
```

I'm working simultaneously with two systems on the NAS so when one system finishes to work - it  "tells" the other by copying a file (File.Copy) to some location.
The second system is listening to that location (don't ask why that's the way of implementing that...it's a long story)
When the copy of the original file is created - the second system searches for the original copy.
This works for all these file, except of sometimes when I get a message that the original's directory doesn't exist...
I see the directory is correct, and it happens only for a few such files. It has to exist (and it actually exists) because the copy came from there....
If anyone has a clue - I'll be glad. 
when the error happens I enter into the following code line:

```
   if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
```

Currently I just added a path - try 50 times, every second, until you find it... I can't check it now, but I guess it will work
Thanks

Comment: What is the content of this `directoryPath` ?

Comment: it's a string, representing the original path which, as said - has to exist. Tested now, the missing started working after 3~7 tries..